# How to fix undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5' from glad.c

Tags: c, opengl, cmake, glfw, glad

I am learning Opengl by following the tutorial at https://learnopengl.com/
and I am having trouble setting up dependency with cmake([See Creating a window](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window)).

I based my CMakeLists.txt on the [GLFW documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(openglTuto)


include_directories(include)
add_executable(gltuto src/main.c src/glad.c)

find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(gltuto glfw)
target_include_directories(gltuto PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(gltuto ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
```

CMake succeed in building my configuration but ninja fail to compile and print an error.

> [1/1] Linking C executable gltuto
>
> FAILED: gltuto
> : && /usr/bin/cc    CMakeFiles/gltuto.dir/src/main.c.o CMakeFiles/gltuto.dir/src/glad.c.o  -o gltuto  /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3.3 && :
>
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/gltuto.dir/src/glad.c.o: undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Comment: `DSO missing from command line` is pretty obvious, you need to add `-ldl`. Though that linker call is really weird in the first place, what with passing absolute paths to libraries.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The linker is complaining about not finding `dlclose`. 
You can add `libdl` with [CMAKE_DL_LIBS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_DL_LIBS.html).
Addtionally, make use of the modern linking with **targets** instead of **strings**.

Change your CMakeLists.txt to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(openglTuto)


add_executable(gltuto src/main.c src/glad.c)

find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(gltuto PUBLIC
                           $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include>
                           $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_link_libraries(gltuto PUBLIC glfw OpenGL::GL ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

Look up [Generator Expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html?highlight=generator%20expressions) to understand `BUILD_INTERFACE` and `INSTALL_INTERFACE`.

Comment: Thanks. As you suggested, simply adding ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} to target_link_libraries did the trick.