# My executable has references to dlcose - but wherefor?

Tags: c++, linux, reverse-engineering, undefined-reference, dlclose

I'm trying to link some executable, built from C++ source files, and getting:

```
/usr/bin/ld: examples/CMakeFiles/whatever/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

Now, I know how to "fix" this:

[How to fix undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5' from glad.c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841870/how-to-fix-undefined-reference-to-symbol-dlcloseglibc-2-2-5-from-glad-c)

but - I don't understand where this dependency is coming from. I'm not dlopen'ing nor dlclose'ing anything that I know of, nor can I think of one of my dependency libraries which does so (although I can't be sure).

How do I investigate the origin of this requirement, to figure out "who's to blame" for the need for `libdl`?

Notes:

- I have control of the build process via CMake.
- I have access to the source files (but not the source file of dependency libraries - just their headers).

Comment: Use `ldd` on dependencies until you find `libdl` in the output?

Comment: @StephenNewell: ldd is for executables, not for `.o` or `.a` files... or am I wrong? **Edit:** It seems I am wrong. `.so` files seem to be usable with ldd.

Comment: Good point, I assumed you were linking against `so`s.  `grep` for `dlclose`.

Comment: Your build output says `main.cpp.o`, so I assume you already checked `main.cpp` without success.

Comment: @StephenNewell: When I grep one  my `main.cpp.o` I get "binary file matches"... I could use objdump or nm, but that won't tell me where the symbol is used.

Comment: Do you have access to the source file?  You could run the pre-processor in case the call is in an inlined function.

Comment: `objdump -D ... | less` and `/dlclose` should give the location.

Comment: @KamilCuk: That didn't do the trick. Tried it also with c++filt before the less, no help either.